# How to filter custom SimpleCursorAdapter

Tags: android, simplecursoradapter

In order to display contacts name and mobile phone number in a `Listview` I created a custom `SimpleCursorAdapter` to populate a `Listview`, this works fine.

Than I added `EditText` control to the layout (on top of the `Listview`) for filtering purpose.

The code for `EditText` follow -

```
final EditText searchText = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.FilterTB);
        searchText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {
                String text = searchText.getText().toString().toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault());
                mySimpleCursorAdapter.getFilter().filter(text);
            }
        });
```

This code **doesn't work**.

How and what is the right way to filter a customer `SimpleCursorAdapter` ??

**EDIT:**

My adapter class follow -

```
public class mySimpleCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {

HashMap selectedList;
Context cntx;

@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    super.bindView(view, context, cursor);

    TextView tt = (TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    String cid = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex( ContactsContract.Contacts._ID ));
    int a = cursor.getPosition();

    if(selectedList.containsKey(cid)){

        tt.setTextColor(Color.RED);
    } else{
        tt.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    }
}

private void saveSelectedList(){

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = cntx.getSharedPreferences("myEvaluators", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String sl = "";
    for (Object key : selectedList.keySet()){
        //iterate over key
        sl = sl + key.toString() + ";";
    }
    if(sl.length()>0) sl=sl.substring(0,sl.length()-1);
    sharedPreferences.edit().putString("evaluators",sl).apply();
}

private void loadSelectedList(){
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = 
cntx.getSharedPreferences("myEvaluators", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    String sl  = sharedPreferences.getString("evaluators","");

    String strArr[] = sl.split(";");

    for (String s: strArr
         ) {
        selectedList.put(s,s);

    }
}

private void clearSelectedItems(){

    for (Object s: selectedList.keySet()
         ) {

        selectedList.remove(s);

    }
    saveSelectedList();
}

public void setClearSelectedItem(String _id, View v){
    TextView tv = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
    if(selectedList.containsKey(_id)){
        selectedList.remove(_id);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        v.setTag(0);
    } else{
        selectedList.put(_id,_id);
        tv.setTextColor(Color.RED);
        v.setTag(null);
    }

    saveSelectedList();
}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {
    return super.newView(context, cursor, parent);
}

public mySimpleCursorAdapter(Context context, int layout, Cursor c, String[] from, int[] to, int flags) {
    super(context, layout, c, from, to, flags);
    selectedList = new HashMap();
    cntx = context;
    loadSelectedList();
}
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work means what is the issue?

Comment: post your adapter class also. what you have did?

Comment: @R2R, issue is when typing letters in the EditText, Listview not filtering

Comment: Can you please update your question with code

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest another approch which is AutoCompleteTextView and SimpleCursorAdapter together for loading contacts...

First put an AutoCompleteTextView to your Activity’s layout xml file.

Here is the activity code

```
public class MainActivity extendsActivity {
SimpleCursorAdapter mAdapter;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance) {
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

//assume that your AutoCompleteTextView element in your xml file is autoCompleteView
AutoCompleteTextView completeTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) findViewById(R.id.autoCompleteView);

mAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, null, 
                             new String[] { Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME },
                             new int[] {android.R.id.text1}, 
                             0);
completeTextView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

mAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
 public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence str) {
   return getCursor(str);
 } });

mAdapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {
 public CharSequence convertToString(Cursor cur) {
   int index = cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);
   return cur.getString(index);
}});
}
}
```

We just have done two different things. 
First calling setFilterQueryProvider. This callback, FilterQueryProvider’s runQuery function is executed everytime when we change something in AutoCompleteTextView. Actually this is the main point.

Secondly, calling setCursorToStringConverter, it is used when we select item, it executes this function to convert cursor to String.

Lastly, one missing point, we haven’t share the getCursor(CharSequence str) function. Let me share it below.

```
public Cursor getCursor(CharSequence str) {
String select = "(" + Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " LIKE ? ";
String[]  selectArgs = { "%" + str + "%"};
String[] contactsProjection = new String[] {
         Contacts._ID,
         Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME,
         Contacts.LOOKUP_KEY,  };

return getContentResolver().query(Contacts.CONTENT_URI, contactsProjection, 
select, selectArgs, null); 
}
```

Add above function to your activity class.

**Don't forget to add READ_CONTACTS permission in Android Manifest file to make this code run properly.**

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I need to list contacts name **and** mobile number in a Listview.

Comment: by using above code you can fetch contact name from `ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME` and mobile number from `ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER`